# What is this plane from WWII (probably French or Allied forces)?

Tags: aircraft-identification, wwii

Picture should have been taken after or during the end of World War II, probably close to Marrakech French base (but that is not sure). Can anyone tell us what these planes are? My grand father could be one of the pilots and I would like to find information on him.[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's an RAF Coastal Command [Vickers Wellington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_Wellington), a maritime patrol variant, with a chin radome for its search radar and the nose turret removed and just greenhouse for observing.  The dark projection on top just above the cowling is a fairing for a Direction Finding loop antenna on the fuselage.  The dark shapes farther back are just dark painted areas.  Here's a shot of a similar one:

[image]

If you're sure the picture was taken near Morocco, it was probably doing sub hunting in the Mediterranean and nearby Atlantic.  Likely with [179 Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No._179_Squadron_RAF), based at Gibraltar.

Comment: It looks to me like the (supercharger? oil cooler?) air inlets on top of the cowlings may be significantly different (taller?) in your photo than in the photo attached to the original question.  Do you agree?  (Doesn't affect the accuracy of the answer, I'm just curious.)

Comment: Also as another side point, the boundaries of the transparent areas on the upper nose are different between the two photos (assuming L and R sides are symmetrical)  .  So clearly we have two different variants here.

Comment: I think what you are thinking of as the air scoop is the teardrop fairing on the fuselage.  The scoops themselves that are white in the pic I posted are black in the OP's pic.  So the whole dark mass is, from left to right, three elements merged into one shape: the back end of the cowl (which bulges up on the Wimpy), the engine inlet scoops, then the DF antenna fairing.  You can also see the mast for another wire antenna sticking up right behind the cockpit.  On the nose, just variations from aircraft to aircraft, as these are likely field mods or at least post production mods.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I don't fully agree; I think the scoops are smaller in the original pic. Just to re-iterate I think the scoops are larger in *your* pic, not vice versa.   I do see the black teardrop fairing of the antenna on the fuselage in both pics.

Comment: A little bit perhaps but it's impossible to tell with such a blurry pic.  In any case, they are the same type, just not the exact same airplanes.

Comment: Thanks you so much ! That's fantastic to have your help and your knowledge ! Many thanks again ! I wil try to investigate further and i will post information if i can find more things. It comes from a serie of pictures taken in Marrakech in 1948-1949 by a french army photographer, friend of my grand-father.

Comment: Following your information, I think the plane in this picture ([from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vickers_Wellington_-_Royal_Air_Force_Coastal_Command,_1939-1945._CM6221.jpg)) is very close to the plane in the original picture. As we can see Gibraltar rock, it should be Squadron 179 as you told.
Thanks again! [![Vickers Wellington - Royal Air Force Coastal Command, 1939-1945](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeCUt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeCUt.png)

Comment: Note that 179 was only running Wimpies until 1944, so your pic must have been taken about 1943 or 44.  Possibly the negs weren't developed until '48 and that's where your dates come from?

Comment: Yes given the new photo posted in new answer I'd say the scoops on top of cowl are slightly shorter (vertically) and somewhat longer (horizontally) in the variant featured in the original post, and also in the new answer by original poster, than in the photo in your answer.  In the OP/ new answer pics the top of the "scoop" structure seems to rise very slightly from front to rear and then start dropping, not so much so in your photo where it seems to be level horizontally and then start dropping off, w/ a shorter overall length but more height.  Just an observation; great answer here anyway.

Comment: RAF passed an order for over 200 'Wellington' heavy bombers around june 1939, this points to war being expected or wanted. This airplane has a very original fuselage construction, a Geodesic frame, shape most known from some domes [![Vickers Wellington fuselage, source: Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o21ZT.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o21ZT.jpg). Blessings +

Comment: It's interesting how geodesic became a kind of aviation dead end.  A great way to make a compound monocoque shape if your available material is long skinny strips or sticks, but inferior to stressed skin in both efficiency and manufacturing ease (the stressed skin being both the structural material and covering).  I have plans for a homebuilt I was intending to build, call the Cygnet, that used a geodetic structure for the wings of thin wood strips to get a decently light and torsionally stiff wing. Very time consuming to make however.